# How to use the filter method inside the map

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

Can't use .filter() inside .map(). I have array "itemsArr"

```
const itemsArr = [9, 10, 13]
```

and other array "data"

```
const data = [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, ... {id: 99}]
```

I am trying to execute code like this:

```
itemsArr.map(item => (
    data.filter((e) => e.id === item).map(item => (
        console.log(item.id)
    ))
))
```

But nothing works and the console is empty.
I want only records with "id" from the "itemsArr" array to be filtered from my "data" array

Code like this works fine:

```
itemsArr.map(item => (
    data.map(item => (
        console.log(item.id)
    ))
))
```

UPD:

```
        {
            itemsArr.map(item => (
                data.filter((e) => e.id === item).map(item => (
                    <div key={item.id}>
                        <Link href={`/${item.cat}`}><a>{item.cat}</a></Link>
                        <Link href={`/${item.cat}/${item.id}`}><a>{item.name}</a></Link>
                        <Link href={`/${item.cat}/${item.id}`}><a></a></Link>
                        <img alt={item.name} src={`/images/${item.imgmdh}`}></img>                          
                    </div>
                ))
            ))
        }
```

Comment: Can you state the objective, please? Is it to get an array of the objects in the `data` array which have ids in the `itemsArr`?

Comment: @danh goal - from the array with "data" objects to display only those IDs that match the array of itemsArr. instead of the console.log I will display the layout

Comment: @danh I added more complete code

Answer (score 1):

No need to map. You can use `includes` to check if the id exists in the `itemsArr`:

```js
const itemsArr = [1,2,3]
const data = [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 99}]

const filtered = data.filter(datum => itemsArr.includes(datum.id))

console.log(filtered)
```

Comment: @MKTF can hit check to accept the answer if it helped you?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array#filter` with `array#some` to get the matched value of `itemsArr` in `data`.

```js
const itemsArr = [9, 10, 13],
      data = [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id:9}, {id: 10}, {id: 99}],
      result = itemsArr.filter(num => data.some(o => o.id === num));
console.log(result);
```